# Php how to escape character of file path

Tags: php, explode, html-escape-characters

```
$filePath="c:\tmp\2012\tmp\test.txt";

$array=explode("\",$filePath);

foreach($array as $test){
    echo $test;
}
```

I want to separate the $filePath by "\", but the escape characters..
How to solve this?
THank you very much

Comment: Easier just to use `/` as it works fine with windows paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to use single quotes:

```
$filePath='c:\tmp\2012\tmp\test.txt';
```

Or double escape:

```
$filePath="c:\\tmp\2012\\tmp\\test.txt";
```

Note you need two slashes in your `explode` call:

```
$array=explode("\\",$filePath);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the "\" characters. This is accomplished by placing it twice.

```
$string = "\\";
echo $string;
```

Result: `\`;

Applying to your code:

```
$filePath="c:\\tmp\\2012\\tmp\\test.txt";
echo $filepath
```

Result: `c:\tmp\2012\tmp\test.txt`

You can also use a single quote instead of a double quote when specifying the path. Which is what I recommend.

```
$filePath='c:\tmp\2012\tmp\test.txt';
echo $filepath
```

Result: `c:\tmp\2012\tmp\test.txt`

Comment: @JasonZ You're welcome. Please select one of the answers as the "best" and upvote them to show your appreciation. Even if you select jszobody instead of me is fine. But the points should go to somebody.